# Worker thread blocking GUI repaint

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

I'm trying to make a login screen for an application. During the login, many SQL calls will be made to a MySQL database, and it may take a few seconds to set everything up. I'd like to display a status screen via Card Layout and update a JLabel while the background thread is running.

Here's the gist of what I have for my Worker Thread:

```
public class LoginPrepThread extends Thread {

    private final UIMain parent;

    public LoginPrepThread(UIMain w){
        parent = w;
    }

    public void exec(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(this);
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            //SqlHelper sql = SqlHelper.instance;
            sleep(500);
            parent.getLoadingLable().setText("Fetching preferences...");
            parent.getMainFrame().revalidate();
            sleep(500);
            parent.getLoadingLable().setText("Scanning workbench...");
            parent.getMainFrame().revalidate();
            sleep(500);
            parent.getLoadingLable().setText("Updating permissions...");
            parent.getMainFrame().revalidate();
            sleep(500);
            parent.getLoadingLable().setText("Finished...Please wait");
            parent.getMainFrame().revalidate();
            sleep(1000);
            parent.getLayout().show(parent.getMainFrame().getContentPane(), "view.main");
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

}
```

Here is how I am calling it (Inside the event of a JButton, after authenticating):

```
setActiveProfile(user);
layout.show(frame.getContentPane(), "view.loading");
frame.repaint();
LoginPrepThread pt = new LoginPrepThread(thisTrick);
pt.exec();
```

I put some dummy events in for now, but the status label doesn't change...any suggestions?

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Another observation:  In your example, you're creating a thread but you never start it (you use it purely as a Runnable), so you never get a background thread going, which is part of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple swing worker solved it. I guess I wasn't good enough on my google'ing

```
public class LoginPrepThread extends SwingWorker<String,String> {

    private final UIMain parent;

    public LoginPrepThread(UIMain w){
        parent = w;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try{
            publish("Fetching preferences...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            publish("Updating permissions...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            publish("Scanning workbench...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            publish("Finalizing...");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            publish("Finished...Please wait");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            parent.getLayout().show(parent.getMainFrame().getContentPane(), "view.main");
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void process(List<String> item) {
        parent.getLoadingLable().setText(item.get(0));
    }

}
```

Comment: Good to see that you've figured out using a SwingWorker. In my answer, I've provided one way of using a `PropertyChangeListener`. This would be a neat way of taking advantage of event-driven programming and keeping your business logic and UI-update logic modular. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Beware: **don't** access any view related instance in doInBackground (as you do at the very last last line ..)

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would be implementing a SwingWorker to perform all your heavy non-GUI related tasks. You should take the advantage of what event-driven programming is all about.

What you need to do would be something like this:

- Implement a PropertyChangeListner to your GUI class, listening to updates. Based on the property changes, update the labels. It is always a good practice to have a single GUI class handle all the GUI related update activities.
- Create a SwingWorker where you would perform your background-intensive tasks. As and when there're updates available, fire a property change event and let the GUI class know that there's an update.

Here's a small [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) example of what you can do:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

/**
 *
 * @author Sujay
 */
public class SimpleWorkerUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements PropertyChangeListener{

    /**
     * Creates new form SimpleWorkerUI
     */
    public SimpleWorkerUI() {
        initComponents();
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        worker.execute();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Current Status: ");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(327, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleWorkerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleWorkerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleWorkerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleWorkerUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SimpleWorkerUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if("status".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())){
            String currentStatus = (String) evt.getNewValue();
            jLabel2.setText(currentStatus);
        }
    }
}

class Worker extends SwingWorker<String, String>{

    private static final int FINAL_VALUE = 1000;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
        int counter = 0;

        while(counter < FINAL_VALUE){
            firePropertyChange("status", "", "value is: "+counter);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(InterruptedException ixe){
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not perform any long-running operations on the event dispatch thread.  You are performing an operation that takes 3 seconds to complete.  During those 3 seconds, you are monopolizing the EDT and no other GUI updates can happen.

Answer (score 0):

You started out with good intentions...

```
public class LoginPrepThread extends Thread {

    private final UIMain parent;

    public LoginPrepThread(UIMain w){
        parent = w;
    }

    public void exec(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(this);
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            //SqlHelper sql = SqlHelper.instance;
            sleep(500);
            parent.getLoadingLable().setText("Fetching preferences...");
            parent.getMainFrame().revalidate();
            sleep(500);
            parent.getLoadingLable().setText("Scanning workbench...");
            parent.getMainFrame().revalidate();
            sleep(500);
            parent.getLoadingLable().setText("Updating permissions...");
            parent.getMainFrame().revalidate();
            sleep(500);
            parent.getLoadingLable().setText("Finished...Please wait");
            parent.getMainFrame().revalidate();
            sleep(1000);
            parent.getLayout().show(parent.getMainFrame().getContentPane(), "view.main");
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what's happening, is when you call `exec` your actually placing a request onto the EDT to call the `run` method, which is then been executed within the EDT, causing the blockage.

Also, in your original example, it's pointless to extend from `Thread` as you never actually start it.

For future reference, I would have a closer look at [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

You are correct (in your self answer), `SwingWorker` is a much easier solution.